# SKTexture in:texture yields empty result

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite-sheet, sktexture

I was trying to cut a sprite sheet and for some reason beyond me the result was always empty.

One would think that the below would give you half the down-left quarter of the image.

```
let allTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "zelda")
let standTex = SKTexture(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 1/2, height: 1/2), in: allTex)
```

This however gives empty results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that CGRect was using the wrong initializer. One would think that the below would give you half the down-left quarter of the image.

```
let allTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "zelda")
let standTex = SKTexture(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 1/2, height: 1/2), in: allTex)
```

This however gives empty results due to the type inference saying the results should be an int followed by some unfortunate rounding of 1/2 being 0. To fix this do this instead:

```
let allTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "zelda")
let standTex = SKTexture(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 1.0/2.0, height: 1.0/2.0), in: allTex)
```

This forces the calculation results to be a double 0.5 and then eventually using CGRect with accurate float instead of rounded int.

Comment: This is not an issue with CGRect, this is an issue with you not specifying what 1 and 2 are, so the compiler is going to assume Int when there are no decimals because Int is the fastest type to work with

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Sure I understand what's going on. Just something that I banged my head against the wall so hoping to save someone else the same. One could run into this in many places but in this particular occurrence it was a bit difficult to realize due to the silent failure and nothing on-screen.

Comment: I was just clarifying why you got the error you got.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks, added mention of type inference to the answer.